# What is the max level in Rogue Legacy?

Tags: rogue-legacy

What is the max possible level in Rogue Legacy? I don't see any sort of experience bar, is level gain based on your generation or the number of monsters slain?

Comment: Not sure about max level, but current level is based on the number of upgrades purchased it seems.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121993/how-is-level-determined

Answer (score 5):

Your level is the same as the number of manor upgrades you have. There are 507 possible upgrades you can make, which means 507 is an absolute max level.

However, since the upgrade costs increases with each upgrade, it may not be possible to achieve enough gold to upgrade the stats that far.